# configure www.example.com as example.com

Tags: nginx, unicorn

I am using nginx as server backend

- sqlbuddy.example.com - for db manage (php-fpm)
- example.com - main site (unicorn)

When I go to  www.example.com I get sqlbuddy.example.com

How do I get example.com at www.example.com

sqlbuddy

```
  server {
    listen sqlbuddy.example.com:80;
    client_max_body_size 1G;
    server_name sqlbuddy.example.com;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    root /home/example/sqlbuddy;
    index index.php;

    location ~ \.php$ {
      fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
      fastcgi_index index.php;

      fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $fastcgi_script_name;
      include fastcgi_params;
    }
  }
```

example.com

```
  upstream example_server {
   server unix:/home/example/application/shared/unicorn.sock fail_timeout=0;
  }

  server {
    listen example.com:80;
    client_max_body_size 1G;
    server_name example.com;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    root /home/example/application/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @example_application;

    location @example_application {
        proxy_pass http://example_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
      root /home/example/application/current/public;
    }
  }
```

default

```
server {
        #listen   80; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name localhost;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }

        location /doc {
                root /usr/share;
                autoindex on;
                allow 127.0.0.1;
                deny all;
        }

        location /images {
                root /usr/share;
                autoindex off;
        }
  }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change the **server_name** directive in your *example.com* container:

```
server {
    listen example.com:80;
    client_max_body_size 1G;
    server_name example.com www.example.com;
    keepalive_timeout 5;
    root /home/example/application/current/public;

    try_files $uri/index.html $uri.html $uri @example_application;

    location @example_application {
        proxy_pass http://example_server;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }

    error_page 500 502 503 504 /500.html;
    location = /500.html {
        root /home/example/application/current/public;
    }
}
```

It is even possible to use wildcards or regular expressions as described [here](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#server_name).